# remove_widget in kivy doesn't remove widget

Tags: kivy

I'm having trouble removing a widget using remove_widget in kivy
I either get TypeError: 'Label' object has no attribute '**getitem**' error
or it just doesn't remove the label that was created.

I think I'm not properly referring to the widget made but not sure how to...

```
Builder.load_string("""


<MenuScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        #cols: 2
        #rows: 2
        size: 800,480

        Button:
            id: resetmash
            text: "Reset"
            font_size: 30
            size_hint: None, None
            background_color: 1,0.88,0.882,1
            size: 100,100 
            pos: 1450,800
            on_press: root.resetmash()
        Button:
            id: btn_0
            text: "+"
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 100,100
            pos: 550,700
            on_press: root.listmashsteps()


""")


class MenuScreen(Screen):



    def resetmash(self):
        self.remove_widget(Label())   

    def listmashsteps(self, *largs):
        self.add_widget(Label(text="Step"))


    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MenuScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)



sm = ScreenManager()
menu_screen = MenuScreen(name='menu')
sm.add_widget(menu_screen)

class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to accomplish here.

Comment: When I click a button it creates a Label, then I want to click another botton to remove the label

Comment: Then create a box (or grid) layout for those labels, so when you want to remove labels, just call `remove_children()` on that box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.remove_widget(Label())
```

This doesn't make sense - you just instantiated that Label, so it isn't already added to the widget, so you can't remove it.

Instead store a reference to the Label when you add it, something like:

```
self.label = Label(text='Step')
self.add_widget(self.label)
```

Then later:

```
self.remove_widget(self.label)
```

Comment: just to follow up. if I'm making multiple label widgets in a loop like def listmashsteps(self, *largs):
        for step in range(0,4):
            self.label = Label(text="Step " + step) then the self.remove_widget(self.label) only removes the last label created. Is there a way to remove all labels that were previous created. It seems labels created aren't indexed so I can't self.remove_widget(self.label[0])

Comment: Look at what the code actually does - it sets `self.label` to point to the instance of the `Label` that you created. If you want to store references to more than one label, you must modify the code appropriately, e.g. `self.labels = []` and `self.labels.append(Label(text='...'))`, then you can modify the labels in self.labels later.

Comment: Thanks again for the response. I get the error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'bind' ` after